# Bluetooth is not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

My Bluetooth is on and visible, yet it does not detect any device and is not being detected by other devices.

I know there are many similar questions around, but non of the proposed solutions seems to work for me.

Some information is listed below, if anything is missing please let me know.

```
$hcitool dev

Devices:    hci0    80:A5:89:40:CF:0A

$hcitool scan
```

(When a detectable device is nearby.)

```
Scanning ...

$lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 13d3:3490 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:57b5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 24ae:1100  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$uname -a

Linux avraham-X556UJ 4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:09:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$lspci -knn

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:1904] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [1043:1c7d]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake Integrated Graphics [1043:246a]
    Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
    Kernel modules: i915_bpo
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem [1043:1c7d]
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [1043:201f]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [8086:9d31] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [1043:1c7d]
00:15.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [8086:9d60] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [1043:1c7d]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [8086:9d61] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [1043:1c7d]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI [1043:1c7d]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:9d03] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1043:1c7d]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d10] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port [8086:9d14] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port [8086:9d15] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9d48] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [1043:1c7d]
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP PMC [1043:1c7d]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [1043:1c7d]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [1043:1c7d]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] [10de:1299] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GK208M [GeForce 920M] [1043:246a]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_361
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:218d]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k


$dmesg | grep -i blue

[    2.265825] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    2.265840] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.265844] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.265847] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.265851] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.273509] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    2.273512] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    2.273513] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    2.273515] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    2.273516] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    2.273517] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    2.273542] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    2.273553] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    2.273554] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    2.553382]  btqca btintel bluetooth wmi acpi_pad tpm_crb int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss int3402_thermal int340x_thermal_zone mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 drm mii ahci libahci i2c_hid hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint video pinctrl_intel fjes
[    3.892139] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.892141] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.892144] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.262379]  lrw snd_seq_device gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper snd_timer cryptd idma64 virt_dma input_leds snd serio_raw soundcore processor_thermal_device intel_soc_dts_iosf mei_me mei shpchp intel_lpss_pci elan_i2c int3403_thermal hci_uart btbcm btqca btintel bluetooth wmi acpi_pad tpm_crb int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss int3402_thermal int340x_thermal_zone mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 drm mii ahci libahci i2c_hid hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint video pinctrl_intel fjes
[    6.546887] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    6.546893] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    6.546897] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    6.810672]  snd_rawmidi aesni_intel snd_seq aes_x86_64 lrw snd_seq_device gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper snd_timer cryptd idma64 virt_dma input_leds snd serio_raw soundcore processor_thermal_device intel_soc_dts_iosf mei_me mei shpchp intel_lpss_pci elan_i2c int3403_thermal hci_uart btbcm btqca btintel bluetooth wmi acpi_pad tpm_crb int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss int3402_thermal int340x_thermal_zone mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 drm mii ahci libahci i2c_hid hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint video pinctrl_intel fjes
[   30.206995]  crc32_pclmul snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi aesni_intel snd_seq aes_x86_64 lrw snd_seq_device gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper snd_timer cryptd idma64 virt_dma input_leds snd serio_raw soundcore processor_thermal_device intel_soc_dts_iosf mei_me mei shpchp intel_lpss_pci elan_i2c int3403_thermal hci_uart btbcm btqca btintel bluetooth wmi acpi_pad tpm_crb int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss int3402_thermal int340x_thermal_zone mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 drm mii ahci libahci i2c_hid hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint video pinctrl_intel fjes
[   30.929506]  crc32_pclmul snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi aesni_intel snd_seq aes_x86_64 lrw snd_seq_device gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper snd_timer cryptd idma64 virt_dma input_leds snd serio_raw soundcore processor_thermal_device intel_soc_dts_iosf mei_me mei shpchp intel_lpss_pci elan_i2c int3403_thermal hci_uart btbcm btqca btintel bluetooth wmi acpi_pad tpm_crb int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss int3402_thermal int340x_thermal_zone mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 drm mii ahci libahci i2c_hid hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint video pinctrl_intel fjes
[   39.576783]  crc32_pclmul snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi aesni_intel snd_seq aes_x86_64 lrw snd_seq_device gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper snd_timer cryptd idma64 virt_dma input_leds snd serio_raw soundcore processor_thermal_device intel_soc_dts_iosf mei_me mei shpchp intel_lpss_pci elan_i2c int3403_thermal hci_uart btbcm btqca btintel bluetooth wmi acpi_pad tpm_crb int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss int3402_thermal int340x_thermal_zone mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 drm mii ahci libahci i2c_hid hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint video pinctrl_intel fjes
```

Comment: You used a wrong button for formatting. Use `{}`. Otherwise it is unreadable.

Comment: Sorry, hopefully it is better now.

Comment: Now it is perfect.

Comment: Do you see any MAC address type directories in directory /var/lib/bluetooth/80:A5:89:40:CF:0A ?  Each device should have one

Comment: Using ls I see "A0:91:69:28:93:53  cache  settings". I have only connected one device (my phone).

Answer (score 0):

This adapter is not supported by Linux kernel yet.

To include this adapter, you need to report a bug to Launchpad by running in terminal

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

Follow directions in your browser to fill the bug report.

Please insclude output of

```
usb-devices | awk '/13d3/' RS=
```

to the description of the bug.

You can leave a link to the bug report and ping me in comments. I will take care of it.

This will not take much time to fix. I will build a test module and the BT will hopefully work with it. In the meantime the support will reach the stable kernels some time.

**Update:** This issue has been fixed in official Ubuntu kernels.

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6. Please see but report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1600623

Comment: I will take care of it tomorrow. `1343` was a typo. The full `usb-devices` is OK.